# Why can't I get an alert BEFORE the appointment?

Tags: calendar, ical

I don't use the Calendar very much, but recently after missing a weekly event twice, I put it in the calendar on the iPad with a "travel time" alert and a fifteen minutes before travel time alert.  Travel time is fifteen minutes.  I was busy on the Macbook and no alert came up there until the actual start time of the meeting.  This happened again another day on the iPad.

Is it a bug, or is there some obscure extra step that needs to be taken?

("Time to Leave" is **ON** in settings.)

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using? Also, did you set the alarm on the iPad or on another device?

Comment: Latest version of everything.  Two (or more) set on the iPad.  One set on the Mac but its time has not arrived yet.  "Time to leave" may not be very useful, since it doesn't ask me whether I'm walking, biking, driving, flying, or teleporting.